# How to remove duplicate Integer elements in array data structure in java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

Is there any simple way to remove duplicate elements in Java(will two loops work and how). Thank you:)

```
IN: int[] arr = {1,3,4,2,3,1,6,7,7};
Output i want is:
{1,3,4,2,6,7}

the only i know is we can traverse it through loop.
 eg.
  for(int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
   for(int j = 0;j<arr.length;j++){

        if(    ){
          //what logic i can apply here.      
          }
     }       
   }
```

Comment: Ok ,I am editing question.please see if this is helpful enough.

Comment: @Tunaki ...I don't think it is an EXACT duplicate.please read the full question and try to understand.If you think it is duplicate question please provide me a link?

Comment: The link is at the top of your question.

Comment: As i am begineer so its hard for to understand that.Can you please resolve it according to my question.I am looking for an easy way which i can understand. Thanks

Comment: Arrays cannot be resized in Java. You have to either return a new array without the duplicates or a different data structure like a list

Answer (score 4):

This should work..

```
final Integer[] noDuplicates =
    new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr)).toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 provides a nice way to do this using [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

```
arr = Arrays.stream(arr) // Convert arr to IntStream
        .distinct()      // Get distinct elements (preserves order)
        .toArray();      // Convert back to array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
int[]arr = {1,3,4,2,3,1,6,7,7};
Set <Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

for ( int w: arr) {
     set.add(w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**i think this would be helpful**

```
 public static int[] removeduplicate(int a[])
 {
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
         for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
         {
            if(a[i]==a[j])
            {
              a[j]=-1;
              count++;
            }
         }
     }
      int b[]=new int[a.length-count];
      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      {
            if(a[i]!=-1)
          {
              for(int j=0;j<(a.length-count);j++)
              {
                   b[j]=a[i];
              }
          }
     }
      return b;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set data structure for removing duplicate elements from an array.

```
   int arr[] = {1, 6, 4, 7, 8, 4, 7, 9, 3, 8};

    Set<Integer> uniqueNumber = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        //It only contains unique element
        uniqueNumber.add(arr[i]);
    }
```

For reference you can check this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HBIMjwte7s. I find it very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

First u cant change the existing array , so need a new array to hold his unique numbers, again as you dont know the number of element in advance better to use ArrayList rather array. If you dont want to write to much logic or less number of loops , u can try this.

```
int[] arr = {1,3,4,2,3,1,6,7,7};
        HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();
         ArrayList<Integer> unique=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int num:arr){
            if(hs.add(num)){
                unique.add(num);
            }

        }
```